# How to convert a .Rnw to an R script

Tags: r, rnw

I want to extract from an RNW all the chunks with R programming and put them in a separate file

I have a long rnw file and would find it tedious to do that manually.

Is there a function or a script to do that ?

Answer (score -1):

You can perform some regex matching to retrieve all the code chunks as follows:

```
#read my Rnw file
l <- readLines("myRnw.Rnw")

#find starting and ending lines of my code chunks
startIdx <- which(grepl("^<<", l))
endIdx <- which(grepl("^@$", l))

#extract all code chunks and save to a file
writeLines(unlist(Map(function(st, ed) l[(st+1):(ed-1)], startIdx, endIdx)),
    "myRcode.R")
```

Comment: There are built-in utilities for this. No need to reinvent the wheel.